# Entity Framework Core Include(...Where)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

According to the docs we have the possibility to use `Where()` inside `Include` in EF Core 5. So this code is working well:

```cs
var groups = dbContext.DocumentGroups
                      .Include(e => e.Types.Where(x => true))
                      .OrderBy(e => e.Name);
```

Now I have to refactor my filter (in this case simplified) - so I tried an extension method like this:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> MyFilter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query)
{
    // ... do a lot of filter stuff here
    return query.Where(e => true);
}
```

and call it like this:

```cs
var groups = dbContext.DocumentGroups
                      .Include(e => e.Types.MyFilter())
                      .OrderBy(e => e.Name);
```

I get an exception:

> The expression 'e.Types.MyFilter(__dbContext_1)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could try extending IQueryable, not IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main thing here is that you need to provide an `Expression` to your include. If you want to refactor and have it as a testable, reusable independent unit you can create for example a static Expression property that you then can pass to the `Include` method.

Something like;

```
public static Expression<Func<MyStoreObject, IEnumerable<MySubType>>> MyIncludeExpression 
{
   get { return e => e.Types.Where(x => true); }
}
```

(`MyStoreObject` being the type of the DocumentGroups, `MySubType` being the type of the property `Types` enumerable.)

and call it with

```
var groups = dbContext.DocumentGroups
                .Include(MyClass.MyIncludeExpression)
                .OrderBy(e => e.Name);
```

See the documentation of the [EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-5.0).

Comment: Following your suggestion I restructured my code - so it is working now, thanks a lot. Nevertheless I do not completely understand the problem because I think ```e => e.Types.MyFilter()``` is an expression and it returns nothing else than the original ```Where()``` clause, doesn't it?

Comment: It's because EF doesn't actually execute your `Where()` returning `IEnumerable<T>` as written -- it recognises that it's a `Where` expression and then translates it into equivalent SQL syntax so that it executes on server-side rather than client-side.  It can't do these sorts of translations for method calls that it doesn't recognise.